# Syntax error: unexpected token in Javascript / posting data to amazon s3

Tags: javascript, syntax, amazon-s3, yui

This is part of my use of the yui uploader:

```
function upload() {
    if (fileID != null) {
        uploader.upload(fileID, "http://url",
        'POST',
        {   AWSAccessKeyId: "keyhere",
            acl: "public-read",
            key: "queue/${filename}",
            policy: "somestring",
            Content-Type: "",
            success_action_redirect: "http://urlhere",
            signature: "sigstring"
        },
        'file');
        fileID = null;
    }
}
```

"Content-Type" is causing a syntax error. I can see the problem. But **the amazon s3 bucket that I am posting to is expecting this variable name**.
So I do not have the option to replace the minus with an underscore or to use CamelCase notion.

How can I submit "Content-Type" as variable name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the Key in Quotes:

```
        "Content-Type": "",
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes:

```
    {   AWSAccessKeyId: "keyhere",
        acl: "public-read",
        key: "queue/${filename}",
        policy: "somestring",
        "Content-Type": "",
        success_action_redirect: "http://urlhere",
        signature: "sigstring"
    },
```